# Native JavaScript alternative for jQuery .contents() method

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a function that scans across HTML DOM tree and does the job.
The problem is that function is written with JQUERY and I have to translate it to native HTML.

Looking for native javascript alternative for jQuery's .contents() method to translate the following line:

```
$myroot.contents().each(function (ind) {.....
```

Assuming that $myroot will be standard HTML element, how can I get all its contents?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Node.childNodes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/childNodes)

Comment: Do you mean vanilla javascript rather than 'native HTML'?

Comment: Sure :) I meant native javascript rather than native HTML :))

Answer (score 1):

If $myroot is something like this

```
$myroot = document.getElementsByClassName("classname");
```

then you can get contents like this

```
Array.prototype.forEach.call(elem, function(elem) {
    // Do stuff here
   console.log(elem.tagName);
});
```

Hope this helps. Thanks !!

Comment: Thanks. Exactly what I was looking for.